# Validation not working with autocomplete in React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an input field that I need to validate. The code works except when the field in filled with autocomplete. How can I fix it?

I have tried to change onBlur for focusout and to change the target in the alert function

```
            <EmailComponent
                email={email}
                onChange={event => {
                    const email = event.target.value
                    const emailIsValid = this.validateEmail(email)
                    console.log(emailIsValid)

                    dispatch(setEmailIsValid(emailIsValid))
                    dispatch(setEmail(email))
                }}
                isSubmittable={!!toolsAnswer && toolsAnswer !== '' && !!email && email !== ''}
                onSubmit={this.onSubmit}
                focusout={this.alertMessage}
            />
        </div>
```

I want the alert message to display if the email is not correct.

Comment: I tried the code as you wrote it (although it lacks a lot of info, like how the email is managed, and what does the onSubmit and alertMessage do) and, even in autocomplete, it does go to the onChange code and enters in the "validateEmail" function.

So, what is the exact behavior you want to get and you are not getting?

Comment: When you click on an email in autocomplete, the validation doesn't trigger because it doesn't register a change with onChange.

Answer (score 0):

Try using onBlur function as you use onChange.